# Can we use regex to resolve multiple rules at once?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am in need to prevent some user input interaction and on top of my mind is `regex` immediately.

I'll first write as best as I can what I need to accomplish and then I'll post the code that I wrote to accomplish most of these, but still not perfect...

- Take the string
- Do not allow it to start typing with a `space`
- Do not allow multiple `spaces` continuously
- Do not allow multiple `dots` continuously
- Do not allow multiple `apostrophies`
- Allow following characters `[a-z] '.`
- Do not allow string to cross over `14 characters`

---

Now, here's my code:

```
this.name = this.name
  .replace(/^[\s]+/, '')     // prevent starting with space
  .replace(/\s\s+/, ' ')     // prevent multiplace spaces
  .replace(/\.\./, '.')      // prevent multiple dots
  .replace(/''/, '\'')       // prevent multiple apostrophies
  .replace(/[^ a-z'.]/i, '') // allowed
  .toUpperCase()             // transform
  .substring(0, 14)          // do not allow more than 14 characters
```

---

Questions:

- Can we and how if so, accomplish all those or most of these regex rules in single replace?
- How can I fix/improve my regex rules to not allow more than single `.`, I made it so that it does not allow continuous entries, but a user can use two dots like `M.G.K` - even tho I want to allow only single `.` entry in whole string?
- Same as above, but for `'` (apostrophe)?

Comment: Try `s.replace(/^\s+|s(\s)+|(\.)\.|(')'|[^ a-z'.\n]+/g, '$1$2$3').toUpperCase().substring(0, 14)`, but the last 2 points are out of scope for a one-pass JS regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew weird, but when I start typing, it allows me to type single letter and then it removes all

Comment: I would recommend readability over cramming a pile of rules together.  Later when you are trying to figure out why it doesn't work and you have a very complicated regex it will be hard.  If you several lines nicely commented it will be easy.  I suspect performance won't be much different.

Comment: @sniperd Well thanks for the information. Still, it's nice to learn that it can be done from Wiktor's sample by `|`. However, I still do need some help improving and learning how to improve my regex rules, as they do not really accomplish what I want to achieve

Comment: Wiktor is a regex pro, his stuff will work well :)  You can cram a lot of the rules together simply use a pipe |

Comment: I needed `i` flag too and I believe you have one minor issue with `|s` there, where it should be `|\s`, no? This seems to work fine now: `/^\s+|\s(\s)+|(\.)\.|(')'|[^ a-z'.\n]+/ig`. However, can anyone assist me by improving my mistakes where characters can be repeated multiple times in whole string (not simultaneously) @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Yes, I made some typos. You need 2 more regex replacements to implement the lsast two requirements. Something like `.replace(/^([^']*'[^']*)'/, '$1').replace(/^([^.]*\.[^.]*)\./, '$1')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - That actually works, even tho I thought it's not possible. I'll need to use `regexr` to see what does each thing mean or if you have time, please write the answer with your comments and describe what each thing does so that I can close this as resolved and explained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first requirement to "cram" everything into 1 regex replace operation is rather easy to implement, because all the replacements you need to do are using the chars that you match. You may use `.replace(/^\s+|(\s)\s+|(\.)\.|(')'|[^ a-z'.]+/ig, '$1$2$3')`, see this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pxS3Zd/1).

**Details**

- `^\s+` - start of string (`^`) and then 1+ whitespaces
- `|` - or
- `(\s)\s+` - a single whitespace captured into Group 1 and then 1+ whitespace chars
- `|` - or
- `(\.)\.` - a `.` captured into Group 2, and then a `.`
- `|` - or
- `(')'` - a `'` captured into Group 3 and then a `'`
- `|` - or
- `[^ a-z'.]+` - 1 or more chars other than a space, ASCII letter, `'` and `.`.

The `/i` modifier makes `a-z` match in a case insensitive way, `g` enables multiple matching. The `$1` refers to the value in Group 1, `$2` references the value in Group 2 and the `$3` refers to the Group 3 value. Note that if they are not matched, these values in groups are empty strings, thus we may use three of them together in a single string replacement pattern.

The second and third requirements require two more separate regex replace operations. The point is to match and capture all chars up to the second occurrence of `'` and `.` and just match the second occurrence of `'` and `.`, and then replace with the backreference to the first group: 1) `.replace(/^([^']*'[^']*)'/, '$1')` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/pxS3Zd/2)) and 2) `.replace(/^([^.]*\.[^.]*)\./, '$1')` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/pxS3Zd/3)).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `([^']*'[^']*)` - Group 1:

  - `[^']*` - any 0+ chars other than `'` (a `[^...]` is a negated character class that matches any chars other than defined inside the class)
  - `'` - a single quote
  - `[^']*` - any 0+ chars other than `'`
- `'` - a single quote.

This match is replaced with `$1`, the contents of the first capturing group.

The third pattern is analogous to the second parttern, just `'` is replaced with `.` / `\.` (note that inside a character class, a `.` is treated as a literal `.`, it does not match any char but line break chars inside `[...]`).

Comment: Much appreciated for the solution, explanation, and demos. Everything works as expected.

Comment: Actually, if you shared your fiddle, it would be much better :)

Comment: Ah, I did not use JSFiddle for this one, even tho I usually do. It's direct dive into a project.

Comment: @dvLden Ok, I'll add one when I'm out of the sandpit. :)